# Vector following the cursor in P5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have created a basic game where the main object (vector player) follow the cursor like in Agar.io. Is there any way to set the player to also rotate itself in the direction of the cursor?

I am after the effect of the rotation like Stabfish.io that the face of the fish is always facing the cursor.

I have managed to sort the following of the cursor on the map but I am wondering how can I solve the rotation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't give any details about how you coded your object it's pretty hard to give you a solution which will match your code, but you are probably looking for the [heading()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/heading) method of the `p5.Vector` class which gives the angle of a vector.

A possible way to use it is this one (that you can test [here](https://codepen.io/statox/pen/dyXKzNe)). Notice how the `draw()` function of the `Mover` uses `rotate()` and the acceleration `heading()` value to make sure the object follows the cursor.

```
function Mover() {
    this.pos = new p5.Vector(width / 2, height / 2);
    this.acc = new p5.Vector(0, -10);

    this.move = () => {
        // Calculate the acceleration towards the mouse position
        this.acc = p5.Vector.sub(new p5.Vector(mouseX, mouseY), this.pos);
        this.acc.setMag(10);
        // Update the position with the acceleration
        this.pos.add(this.acc);
    };

    this.draw = () => {
        push();
        // Translate to the object position
        translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
        // Rotate following the acceleration
        rotate(this.acc.heading());
        // Draw the object, could be a shape or a sprite or anything
        rect(0, 0, 50, 10);
        pop();
    };
}

let m;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(700, 700);
    m = new Mover();
}

function draw() {
    background(50);
    m.move();
    m.draw();
}
```

Comment: thanks man, It make sense however I have created my vectors slightly different and the whole translate thingy has kind of confused my perception of the actual position - the whole canvas seems to be now infinite. If I share my source code with you would you be happy to advice?  I can also share the code here inside of the answer to my question

Comment: My player is following the cursor but then I would like to also display the arrow (e.g. in the top right corner (fixed position). Is there any possibility to e.g create an object e.g. point to collect in random position on the map and then every time this coin appears the arrow indicates where it is on the map - kind of like snake, you collect the points and need to avoid upcoming obstacles - the issue is the actual world is bigger than canvas so the player won't know where the coin appears.

Comment: I've just started coding so the code might be sligthly messy, and the code below was done following some yt tutorials. It works but now the issue is the arrow.

Comment: Instead of creating an answer, it's usually recommended to edit your question and add the code you want to show. Now no matter how you did your code the idea is still the same: You need a vector going from your current player position to the target position, using `.heading()` on this vector will give you an angle between 0 and 2*PI this is the orientation your player will need to follow. Now whether you want your player sprite to face this direction or another sprite the idea is the same: you use `translate` move at the position where you want to draw the sprite...

Comment: ... and then you use `rotate(angle)` (where `angle` is the `heading()` I mentioned previously) to turn in the right direction and you can then draw your sprite. And you probably want to surround your `rotate()` and the drawing with `push()` and `pop()` (see [the doc](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push)) to make sure that you don't mess up the drawing state and can continue to draw the next frames in the same referential.

Comment: hi, are you able to assist with the following issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696584/collision-check-between-vectors-moving-vectors-html-js-p5

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Player {
    constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.pos = createVector(x, y);
    this.r = r;
    this.vel = createVector(500, 500);
    this.mag = 1;
    this.velLerp = 0.1;
    this.score = 0;
  }

  // player is following the coursor, adjust 0,05 for delay
  update() {
    let mouse = createVector(mouseX - width / 2, mouseY - height / 2);
    mouse.setMag(this.mag);
    this.vel.lerp(mouse, this.velLerp);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);

    if (
      this.pos.x <= MAP_WIDTH &&
      this.pos.x >= 0 &&
      this.pos.y > 0 &&
      this.pos.y < MAP_HEIGHT
    ) {
      mouse.setMag(this.mag);
      this.vel.lerp(mouse, this.velLerp);
      this.pos.add(this.vel);
    } else {
      //this.pos.add(10.1, 11);
      this.pos.sub(this.vel);
      this.r -= 0;
    }
  }
```

Then I have in other file that is connect and scripted below in html;

```
translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  let newzoom = 30 / player.r;
  zoom = lerp(zoom, newzoom, 0.1);
  scale(zoom);
  translate(-player.pos.x, -player.pos.y);

push();
  player.draw();
  pop();
  player.update();
```

There is more code obviously but I am trying to write only what is related to discussed issue.